# Вставлять блок мероприятия на сайт до определенного времени

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Есть `baner.html`, в котором лежит:

```
<div class="rec" id="intro-dm">
   <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="https://festnext.com/"> 
    <img id="recim" src="wow/1e25ca161855538d40b45cee2f3e27d6/IMG/banner/rec_mal.jpg" width="100%" alt="Приглашение на выступление"/></a>
</div>
```

Нужно чтобы код из файла вставлялся в `<div class="Baner" id="baorzon"></div>` до наступления определенного времени (например 29.06.19:20:00:000 Мск).Не пользовательского времени, а общего.

Как это реализовать, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было лишь менять содержимое `baner.html`, и время до которого оно видно?

На данный момент вставляю через:

`<link rel="import" ...>`

```
var link = document.querySelector('link[rel=import]');
var content = link.import.querySelector('#intro-dm'); 
document.body.appendChild(content.cloneNode(true));
```

Comment: Пока вставляю через  `<link rel="import" ...>` и  `<script>
      var link = document.querySelector('link[rel=import]');
      var content = link.import.querySelector('#intro-dm');
      document.body.appendChild(content.cloneNode(true));
    </script>` , а со временем совсем не знаю да и знаний мало

Comment: Можно отсылать время с сервера ajax`ом, вместо пользовательского.

Comment: Я очень  слаб в Js, приведите пожалуйста пример

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По факту мы можем использовать время на клиенте:

- записывать даты окончания мероприятия в формате UTC+0;
- прибавлять к нему клиентское смещение по времени;
- разницу полученного времени и текущего клиентского считать критерием окончания или актуальности мероприятия.

---

В качестве примера.

```js
// Текущая дата/время на клиенте.
const DATE_NOW = new Date();

// Блок для вывода информации.
const BAORZON = document.querySelector('#baorzon');

// Массив мероприятий.
const REMAININGS = [{
  "title": "Посмотреть тур",
  "link": "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour",
  "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/180x180/FFFF00/000000?text=Картинка+1",
  "expired_at": "2019-07-01 3:45" // UTC+0
}, {
  "title": "Почитать справку",
  "link": "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help",
  "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/180x180/000000/FFFFFF?text=Картинка+2",
  "expired_at": "2019-07-01 20:05" // UTC+0
}, {
  "title": "Подправить даты в ответе",
  "link": "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help",
  "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/180x180/0000FF/808080?text=Картинка+3",
  "expired_at": "2020-07-01 16:01" // UTC+0
}];

// Ищем и отрисовываем первое мероприятие,
// срок которого еще не истек.
renderRemaining(findRemaining(REMAININGS));

// // Либо подгружаем файл `*.json`.
// fetch('remainings.json')
//     .then((response) => response.json())
//     .then(function(remainings) {
//         renderRemaining(findRemaining(remainings));
//     })
//     .catch(function(err) {
//         console.error('Не удалось загрузить список мероприятий', err);
//     });

// Поиск первого мероприятия, срок которого еще не истек.
function findRemaining(remainings) {
  return remainings.find(function(remaining) {
    // Получим дату, когда истекает срок мероприятия
    // в формате UTC + смещение по клиентскому времени.
    let dt = dateFromString(remaining.expired_at);

    // Проверяем, что дата мероприятия истекла/не истекла.
    // Если истекла - `true`, не истекла - `false`.
    let expired = (dt - DATE_NOW) < 0;

    // Нам нужно мероприятие "не просрочка".
    // Возвращаем булево значение. Не запутайтесь!
    console.log('expired: '+expired, dt - DATE_NOW, dt, DATE_NOW);

    return !expired;
  });
}

// Отрисовка мероприятие на странице.
function renderRemaining(remaining) {
  // Если нашли активное мероприятие.
  if (remaining) {
    let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    let img = document.createElement('img');

    wrapper.id = 'intro-dm';
    wrapper.classList.add('rec');
    link.href = remaining.link;
    link.target = '_blank';
    img.src = remaining.image;
    img.alt = remaining.title;
    img.title = remaining.title;

    BAORZON.appendChild(wrapper);
    wrapper.appendChild(link);
    link.appendChild(img);
  } else {
    BAORZON.innerHTML = 'Нет активных мероприятий.'
  }
}

// Парсинг даты/времени из формата YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
// в формат UTC + смещение по клиентскому времени.
// Либо используйте `new Date(dateString);`, где `dateString` в формате
// http://es5.javascript.ru/x15.9.html#x15.9.1.15
function dateFromString(str) {
  const matches = str.match(/^(\d{4})\-(\d{1,2})\-(\d{1,2})\s+(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})$/);

  if (6 !== matches.length) return false;

  return new Date(Date.UTC(
    parseInt(matches[1], 10), // год
    // исчисление месяцев начинается с нуля
    parseInt(matches[2], 10) - 1, // месяц
    parseInt(matches[3], 10), // день
    parseInt(matches[4], 10), // час
    parseInt(matches[5], 10) // минут
  ));
}
```

```html
<div class="baner" id="baorzon"></div>
```